# How to serve file in webpy?

Tags: python, web.py

I am using webpy framefork. I want to serve static file on one of requests. Is there special method in webpy framework or I just have to read and return that file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are running the dev server (without apache):

> Create a directory (also known as a folder) called static in the location of the script that runs the web.py server. Then place the static files you wish to serve in the static folder.
>
> For example, the URL http://localhost/static/logo.png will send the image ./static/logo.png to the client.

Reference: http://webpy.org/cookbook/staticfiles

---

Update. If you really need to serve a static file on `/` you can simply use a redirect:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import web

urls = (
  '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        # redirect to the static file ...
        raise web.seeother('/static/index.html')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

if __name__ == "__main__": app.run()
```

Comment: thats serves files in /static path only, I need to serve index.html on request with path /

Comment: this only works if you run the web.py app directly from the folder where it sits. if you want to run /path/to/my/web/app.py you're out of luck.

Answer (score 6):

I struggled with this for the last couple of hours... Yuck!

Found two solutions which are both working for me...
1 - in .htaccess add this line before the ModRewrite line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/.*
```

This will make sure that requests to the /static/ directory are NOT rewritten to go to your code.py script.

2 - in the code.py add a static handler and a url entry for each of several directories:

```
urls = (
    '/' , 'index' ,
    '/add', 'add' ,
    '/(js|css|images)/(.*)', 'static', 
    '/one' , 'one'
    )

class static:
    def GET(self, media, file):
        try:
            f = open(media+'/'+file, 'r')
            return f.read()
        except:
            return '' # you can send an 404 error here if you want
```

Note - I stole this from the web.py google group but can't find the dang post any more!

Either of these worked for me, both within the templates for web.py and for a direct call to a web-page that I put into "static"

Comment: Did you see some benefit to these methods over http://webpy.org/cookbook/staticfiles ?

Comment: I got this to work - I could not get other methods to work, so I guess that's an advantage ;-) I was working on a shared hosting account so that may have been some of my struggle.

Comment: +1 - This seems like the right solution when you want to restrict access to the files you'll be serving.

Comment: just as a warning, this will permit someone to request URLs like: /images/../../../../somefile_you_dont_want_anyone_to_see

Comment: @ZachDwiel - Thanks! Great to know that I have left that hole open. Any thoughts about a good way to close it?

Comment: The safest thing would most likely to not use webpy for this, but if you must it seems that removing '..' and leading '/' from media and file would be a good start

Comment: for the 2nd solution, how would you format the GET request to include the `media` and `file` params?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend serving static files with web.py. You'd better have apache or nginx configured for that.

Comment: why not? it would be beneficial to understand your reasons.

Comment: Because it will be slow

Answer (score -1):

The other answers did not work for me.
You can first load the html file in app.py or even write the html within app.py.
Then, you can make the index class' GET method return the static html.

```
index_html = '''<html>hello world!</html>'''

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return index_html
```