# Problems with boostrap (begginer)

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4, web.py

I am trying to create web page using web.py and I've added bootstrap and ripples. But when I run it, I get the following **errors**:

```
 - - [17/Aug/2020 08:56:01] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 200 OK
 - - [17/Aug/2020 08:56:01] "HTTP/1.1 GET /static/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" - 404 File not found
 - - [17/Aug/2020 08:56:01] "HTTP/1.1 GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.css" - 404 File not found
 - - [17/Aug/2020 08:56:01] "HTTP/1.1 GET /static/js/material.min.js" - 404 File not found
 - - [17/Aug/2020 08:56:01] "HTTP/1.1 GET /static/js/ripples.min.js" - 404 File not found
 - - [17/Aug/2020 08:56:01] "HTTP/1.1 GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.css" - 404 File not found
 - - [17/Aug/2020 08:56:01] "HTTP/1.1 GET /static/js/material.min.js" - 404 File not found
 - - [17/Aug/2020 08:56:01] "HTTP/1.1 GET /static/js/ripples.min.js" - 404 File not found
```

Maybe can be because I am using old libraries or don't know why. **This is the code where I am using it**:

*MainLay.html*:

```
$def with (page)
<!-- se hace uso de bootstrap definiendo una variable llamada css-->
$var css: static/css/bootstrap.min.css static/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css

<!-- se hace uso de jquery definiendo una variable llamada js-->
$var js: static/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js static/js/bootstrap.min.css static/js/material.min.js static/js/ripples.min.js
```

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751508/how-to-serve-file-in-webpy

Comment: @LiewXun So this is not a problem of the files, is just a problem of the server?

Comment: If the files are in the correct path, yes, it is the server that isn't serving those static files.

Answer (score 0):

the given path is in correct go to properties of each directory copy the path and refresh it may work or give links instead reading locally the chances of getting errors through links are less

You can find links here : [https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/][1]

Comment: So this is not a problem of the files, is just a problem of the server?