# How to return static HTML pages within a directory using web.py?

Tags: python, web.py

I have a web app built with web.py that generates some HTML files and serves them up to the front end. Just by going through the web.py tutorial, it seems I need to explicitly create a class for each static HTML page I serve, but that won't work for my purposes if my web app is generating these HTML files on the fly. Ideally, I'd have one directory `cache/` where I put all of my HTML files, and sending a GET request to `<IP_address_of_server>:8080/cache/<any_number>.html` will return the one I want. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serve file in webpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751508/how-to-serve-file-in-webpy)

Comment: sort of? i'm not sure how to format a GET request that includes the new parameters

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression in your urls(), for example:

```
urls = (
    '/foobar/(.*)\.html', 'MyHandler',
    )
```

Then, your handler will get one parameter as input, which can by your file name to serve.

```
class MyHandler:
    def GET(self, filenumber):
        with open('cache/' + filenumber + '.html') as fp:
            return fp.read()
```

Calling `/foobar/15567.html` will result in `MyHandler.GET()` with `filename="15567"`. which allows you to find and read and return the contents of that file.

Note **do not** do it this simply: Queries for, for example, `/foobar/../root/passwd.txt`  will result in users being able to "look outside" of your cache subdirectory, possibly doing things you do not want to do -- you should check your input (the value of `filenumber`), for example, make sure it is all numeric, or a simple file name (no / or ..) or the resulting normalized path starts with your expected path.):

```
os.path.normpath('cache/' + filenumber + '.html).startswith('cache/')
```