# GET() missing 1 required positional argument : how do i format a GET request to include parameters?

Tags: python, web.py

I have a webapp with the following code, which is supposed to serve up any .html file I have stored in the `htmls/` directory, provided the two parameters `urlhash` and `predictiontag` are correct.

```
import web

urls = (
    '/htmlview/(.*)', 'htmlview'
)

class htmlview:
    def GET(self, urlhash, predictiontag):
        cache_dir = os.path.join("htmls\\", urlhash)
        htmlpath = os.path.join(cache_dir, predictiontag + ".html")
        with open(htmlpath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            data = f.read()
        return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

I don't know how to format the GET request from a browser window in order to actually access these files. I tried `http://localhost:8080/htmlview/a?urlhash=6355865449554195623&predictiontag=Primary` but it gave me the error:

```
<class 'TypeError'> at /htmlview/a
GET() missing 1 required positional argument: 'predictiontag'
```

For reference, here is the other post I was following: [How to serve file in webpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751508/how-to-serve-file-in-webpy)

Comment: Use CamelCase for class names and snake_case for field and method names. (C) PEP8

Comment: Where is your code that calls the method?

Comment: Check (print) the content of parameter `urlhash` - it could be that the string with all parameters is passed there

Comment: @Barmar it should be the last line `app.run()`. i believe the web.py framework handles the actual call

Answer (score 0):

I use flask but I am guessing that webpy wants you to specify multiple groups in the url matching pattern. (.*) probably matches the whole query string as a single argument to the GET function.  Maybe you can use something like
`urls = ('/htmlview/(.*)&(.*)', 'htmlview')`

Again, just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, here is what worked for me:

```
urls = (
    '/htmlview/(.*)/(.*)', 'htmlview'
)

class htmlview:
    def GET(self, urlhash, predictiontag):
        cache_dir = os.path.join("htmls\\", urlhash)
        htmlpath = os.path.join(cache_dir, predictiontag + ".html")
        with open(htmlpath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            data = f.read()
        return data
```

It seems web.py automatically takes the first `/(.*)` to be the first parameter and the second to be the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `urls` regular expression to match url **path**.

Use `web.input()` to access **query string**.

For your example url: `http://localhost:8080/htmlview/a?urlhash=6355865449554195623&predictiontag=Primary`

```
url = ( '/htmlview/(.*)', 'htmlview', )
```

Will pass *only* 'a' as the first parameter to `htmlview.GET()`. The remainder is obtainable *within* `htmlview.GET()` using web.input():

```
class htmlview:
    def GET(self, path):
        urlhash = web.input().urlhash
        predictiontag = web.input().predictiontag
```